# Authentication throught a form using a Node.js route that is connected to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, authentication

I developed a Node.js API that executes its requests on a MySQL database. I also created a PHP webapp that uses this Node.js API.

I would need now to implement an authetication feature on my web application. The informations of my users are stored in the MySQL database.

So for the web part I made a form that sends a POST request, with all the user's informations, linking to a route in the API.

Then for the Node.js part, I have read that passport module makes authentication simple, but I am having issues setting it up with what I get from the POST request.

Can someone explain me how I should do that ?

I do not know which code I have to show you for a better understanding of my issue, so just ask if you want any further explanation or code snippets from what I have already.

Comment: What issues are you having ?

Comment: I am having issues writting the code for the route that will authenticate the user